# Lag between clicking Next JS route and page being loaded

Tags: javascript, performance, next.js

I just pushed a site live here: https://sconi.com.au/
And the delay between clicking the header links and anything happening can be up to 2 seconds.
This is a very basic site and I can't imagine would take that long to load on live. Works great on stage and localhost so not sure what would be different live.

EDIT: It loads slower and slower the more you click around until it just crashes all together. I assume this is a memory leak right?

I have found the trouble code. Why does this slow my site down every page load?

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined'
if (isBrowser) {
  this.setState({ isLoading: false })
}

//Router events to check if we have changed page
//If we have then we are loading and the loading spinner should display
Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true })
})

Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
  //Router events to check if we ahve completed the router change
  //If we have then we are not loading and the loading spinner should be removed
  this.setState({ isLoading: false })
})

Router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => {
  //Any router change errors remove the loader
  this.setState({ isLoading: false })
})
```

Anyone have any debugging suggestions? Tried a few things that amounted to nothing.

Thanks

Comment: You should call `Router.events.off` in a `useEffect`'s return ([cleanup phase](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)) to cleanup the listeners. Also, using `useRouter` is preferred over directly accessing the `Router` object.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the network calls, it seems like you're downloading more than 28MB of data on each page load.
You can defer all the off-screen images using any lazy loading technique.
Also, there are too many unused JS codes in your bundle. Use a bundle analyzer tool and remove all the dead code to improve the render performance.

You can get all the performance stats by audting your site through [Light House](https://web.dev/measure/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. While there are some optimisations to be made I edited the question based on new findings. Cheers